# NP Solvable in Polynomial Time

Tags: algorithms, np-complete

I just took an exam and am a little curious about this question (it may not be verbatim, but the idea is clear):

TRUE/FALSE: If an NP complete problem can be solved in polynomial time, then P = NP.

My thought was FALSE.  A single NP-complete problem being solved in polynomial time doesn't prove that P = NP, it just proves that this one problem $\in$ P.

It made sense during the exam, but I'm not too confident now.

Comment: If I understand correctly, a problem Q is NP complete if any NP problem can be reduced to Q in polynomial time. In this case you were incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You're incorrect. If some NP-complete problem $A$ can be solved in polynomial time, then given any other NP problem $B$ we can solve it in polynomial time by first reducing $B$ to $A$ in polynomial time and then running the polynomial algorithm for $A$. A nearby statement is false, namely, that if a problem in NP can be solved in polynomial time then $P=NP$. Any problem in $P$ is a counterexample-unless, of course, $P=NP$!

Comment: Ah, I totally forgot that all NP problems can be reduced to each other. Damn.

Comment: Not all NP problems! (unless P=NP) That's the point of the "complete" in NP-complete.

Comment: @steveclark Yes, be careful here. $\operatorname{NP}$ means problems are _verifiable_ in polynomial time. $\operatorname{NP}$-complete means the problems are in $\operatorname{NP}$ and can also be reduced to any other problem that is $\operatorname{NP}$-complete. A related concept is $\operatorname{NP}$-hard, which is a set of problems that are at least as hard as the $\operatorname{NP}$-complete ones.